# How to show alert on tags remove using angularJs?

Tags: angularjs, alert, ng-tags-input

I am using ng-tags-input library for showing tags but I would like to show a sweetAlert while user remove tags. I try this but I noticed that tag removed before alert shown on screen. see below screenshots.

[image]

[image]

From second screenshot you can see when I remove tag July-2017 it will remove July-2017 tag before confirmation on alert box. In this case there is no means of using alert box.

At coding level I did this

**HTML**

```
<tags-input ng-model="monthTags" display-property="text" placeholder="{{ ''}}" add-from-autocomplete-only="true"  on-tag-removed="removeDiv($tag)" add-on-paste="true" on-tag-added="addDiv($tag)"  ng-required="true">
    <auto-complete  min-length="1" source="loadTags($query)"> </auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.removeDiv = function (tag) {

    if (tag.id) {
        swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "You want to remove this.",
            showCancelButton: true,
            type: "warning",
            confirmButtonColor: "#37BC9B",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
            closeOnConfirm: true,
        },
        function () {
            //Ajax request
        });
    }
}
```

Now What I need to do to achieve this. Please help

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onTagRemoving` callback of ngTagsInput. It's [in the documentation](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/documentation/api#tagsInput). It states that

> Expression to evaluate that will be invoked before removing a tag. The
>   tag is available as $tag. This method must return **either a boolean
>   value or a promise**. If either a false value or a rejected promise is
>   returned, the tag will not be removed.

You need to change the `on-tag-removed` to `on-tag-removing` & returns the boolean true to remove or false to revert.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but a promise should be returned instead of a boolean value, since it is an asynchronous operation (it relies on the user to do something).

Comment: @MichaelBenford It can return either value from promise & boolean according to their official documentation. Also i have tried in fiddle. Returning boolean works

Comment: I'm aware of what the documentation says, mainly because I am the person who wrote it. :) Returning a boolean only works for synchronous operations, but the OP described an asynchronous scenario (a dialog on the screen waiting for the user to decide what to do). For such a scenario, a promise must be returned.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `promise` because here a dialog on the screen waiting for the user to decide what to do. I try to give you some hints with your code, like:

**HTML**

```
<tags-input ng-model="monthTags" display-property="text" placeholder="Add Months" add-from-autocomplete-only="true"  on-tag-removed="removeDiv($tag)" add-on-paste="true" on-tag-added="addDiv($tag)"  ng-required="true">
    <auto-complete  min-length="1" source="loadTags($query)"> </auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.removeDiv = function (tag) {
    let promiseDivRemove = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if (tag.id) {
            swal({
                title: "Are you sure?",
                text: "You want to remove this.",
                showCancelButton: true,
                type: "warning",
                confirmButtonColor: "#37BC9B",
                confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
                closeOnConfirm: true,
            },
            function (isConfirm) {
                if (isConfirm) {
                    //Ajax request
                    resolve(true);    
                } else { reject(false);}
            });
        }else{ reject(false);}
    }).then(
        function(result) { return result; },
        function(error) { return error; }
    );;
    return promiseDivRemove;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should show the alert inside the success function of the request.

```
$http.get(url).remove().then(function (response) {
   showAlert();
})
.error(function(error){

})
```

Comment: @Ramkishan what is the result?

Comment: Not working because tag removed before alert box shown on screen

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for confirmation from user is true or false like this:

```
$scope.removeDiv = function (tag) {
  if (tag.id) {
      swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",`enter code here`
        text: "You want to remove this.",
        showCancelButton: true,
        type: "warning",
        confirmButtonColor: "#37BC9B",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
        closeOnConfirm: true,
    },
    function (isConfirm) {
             if(isConfirm){
                    Ajax request
              }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Tags has removed before alert box shown on screen  @jenny.

Comment: Unfortunately your answer didn't solve my problem :(

Comment: @Ramkishan please put  on-tag-removing="removeDiv($tag)" inplace of on-tag-removed="removeDiv($tag)" in tags-input tag in html.

Comment: I tried this too as @Agam Banga has suggested, but this didn't work me too.

Comment: @Ramkishan can you create plunker?

Answer (score 0):

```
<tags-input ng-model="tags" on-tag-removing="validateRemoval($tag)"></tags-input>

  $scope.validateRemoval = function(tag) {
     alert('Are you sure you want to delete?');
  }
```

Comment: This answer was flagged for review (NAA), please [edit] and include proper description about the code - I reviewed this as "Looks OK" because the code itself is correct, but still need explanation for future users with the same problem