# Function is returning before modal returns AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, tags

Ive been trying to figure out a way to have my function wait for my modal window to close before returning, but nothing I've tried has worked. I have a angularjs component that allows a user to add and remove tags. When the user removes a tag i want it to call my modal window and have them confirm if they want to delete the tag. However the function returns before the user can make their choice.

This is my tag html code. Im using npm tags-input. The attribute on-tag-removing expects a bool to be returned

```
<tags-input ng-model="formVm.form.tags" on-tag-removing="removingTagModal()" ></tags-input>
```

This is my angularjs code for opening the modal.

```
$scope.removingTagModal = function() {
          
               var promiseDivRemove = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
                $modal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'removeTagModal.html',
                    controller: 'RemoveTagModalController',
                    size: 'lg',
                    resolve: {
                    }
                  }).result.then(function(item) {
                    resolve(item);    
                });
            });
            return promiseDivRemove;
            };
```

Here is the controller code for the modal

```
 .controller('RemoveTagModalController', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', function($scope, $modalInstance) {
     
      $scope.ok = function() {
       
        $modalInstance.close(true);
      };

      $scope.cancel = function() {
        $modalInstance.close(false);
      };
      


    }])
```

Comment: IIRC, methods on the modal instance also return promises which must be forwarded. So `$scope.ok = function() { return $modalInstance.close(true); }; ` etc.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I added the return to the modal instance method and its still returning before the user can select a Ok or Cancel

Comment: I see. It's been awhile since I've worked with angularjs but I think you should remove your error Handler which returns false from the modal invocation. That could certainly suppress a number of errors and it's best to use the promise to handle errors directly

Comment: @AluanHaddad i added a promise but still no luck. Does it look like im doing it right?

Comment: No. You're misusing the promise Constructor and you don't need it at all. What I mean is using `.catch` to handle errors. You chain the call so it comes after `.then`. Really though, I would remove all error handling until you get it right because you're suppressing useful information. Anyway you don't want to use the promise Constructor

Comment: I got that answer from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43579922/how-to-show-alert-on-tags-remove-using-angularjs/58562339#58562339. It odd because its not throwing any errors. Its just returning sooner than i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found a workaround. Instead of having the function wait to return I just return false every time. But once the user selects their choice if the choose okay to delete the tag I delete the tag manually in the js code.

Here is my updated solution

```
 $scope.removingTagModal = function($tag) {
           
            $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'removeTagModal.html',
                controller: function($scope, $modalInstance){
                    

                    $scope.ok = function() {
                        
                        $modalInstance.close(true);
                     };
               
                     $scope.cancel = function() {
                        
                        $modalInstance.close(false);
                     };
                 },
                size: 'lg',
                
              }).result.then(function(item) {
                if(item){
                    var idx = $scope.formVm.form.tags.indexOf($tag);
                    $scope.formVm.form.tags.splice(idx, 1);
                }
            });

            return false;
    
            };
```

Comment: I'm glad you found a workaround, but I noticed something here which I didn't realize previously, you're not returning the promise returned by opening the modal dialog. Promise propagation is critical to understand if one is to write correct code. The caller of an asynchronous operation should almost always be responsible for deciding if they want to fire and forget or not.